# Set proxy server specific to a service request HTTP client+REST

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-rest

```
using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
            {
                var response = client.GetAsync(fullUrl).Result;
}
```

I am creating HTTP client as above to consume a RESTfull service.
I should be able to set proxy for  this service request.
How can I set proxy server specific to this service request only?

Comment: I am using System.Net.Http.HttpClient

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**uSING Microsoft.Http I can**

```
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                /*Set Credentials to authenticate proxy*/
                client.TransportSettings.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxyAddress);
                client.TransportSettings.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                client.TransportSettings.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(this.baseUrl);
                var response = client.Get(fullUrl);

                var jsonResponce = response.Content.ReadAsJsonDataContract<mYResponseoBJECT>();


 public static T ReadAsJsonDataContract<T>(this  HttpContent content)
        {
            return (T)content.ReadAsJsonDataContract<T>(new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T)));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

System.Net.Http.HttpClient don't have TransportSettings propert and about Microsoft.Http assembly is unknown.